# Is there a way to query unique substrings/prefixes of keys in hazelcast map using sql predicate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hazelcast

Using Java, spring, hazelcast, map

In a map all keys are obviously unique, but I'm searching for a way to query all unique prefixes or substrings?

such that I find

```
groupId1
groupId2
```

if I query this map

```
groupId1 + "_" + key1, value 1
groupId1 + "_" + key2, value 2
groupId2 + "_" + key1, value 3
```

I have looked here but don't find anything that satisfies my requirement.
https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/query/how-distributed-query-works

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [Hazelcast 5.1 or later](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/sql/functions-and-operators#string-functions)

If your key is a string then you could do something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(__key FROM 1 FOR 2)) FROM m
```

assuming the length is fixed.

If the length isn't fixed, just make the key a POJO, and use

```
SELECT DISTINCT(field1) FROM m
```